# Maya Python script to show numerical vertex translation

Tags: python, api, position, maya, vertex

I want to write a script for Maya in Python which allows you to see the numerical translation of a Vertex in a headup display.

So if a pick one Vertex and move it along an axis, in the headup display should appear the moved value since the start world position of the Vertex.

as example the world position is '20, 20 , 50' of teh vertex and I move it to '20, 20 , 30' in the headup display should be display '0 0 20'.

I am far away but this is what I have done until now.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

selection = cmds.ls(sl=True) 

for obj in selection:
    vertexWert = cmds.pointPosition( obj , w=True)

print vertexWert
```

Comment: How can we help you? What is your question/error? Are you stuck with "printing stuff on the HUD"?

Comment: I stuck with the math part. I need to bring the logic in the script. I need an idea to have the variabls which have the right value in it.

Comment: are you working on cached objects ? I don't understand the aim of your script

Answer (score 2):

You can get a notification about the change with an `attributeChanged` scriptJob on the `.outMesh` attribute of the object to fire a script when the mesh is edited. However that won't know *why* the mesh changed: for example it will fire if you rotate a vertex selection instead of moving it.  You'll have to store a copy of the vert positions and compare the new ones with the old ones to get the actual difference.

Here's a very basic example which uses prints (the [headsUpDisplay](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/headsUpDisplay.html) command is very wordy so I'll leave that out). I'm also using a global variable, which in general is a bad idea but it sounds like adding classes into the problem will make it harder to demonstrate:  the 'right' thing to do is to make a callable class that manages the mesh differences for you.

```
# to save the mesh positions. This does mean you can only use this code on one object at a time....
global _old_positions
_old_positions = None

# this is the callback function that gets called when the mesh is edited
def update_mesh_positions():
    selected = cmds.ls(sl=True, o=True)
    if selected:
        selected_verts = selected[0] + ".vtx[*]"
        global _old_positions
        # make sure we have something to work with....
        if not _old_positions:
            _old_positions = cmds.xform(selected_verts, q=True, t=True, ws=True)

        # gets all of the vert positions
        new_positions = cmds.xform(selected_verts, q=True, t=True, ws=True)

        # unpack the flat list of [x,y,z,x,y,z...] into 3 lists of [x,x], [y,y], etc...
        x1 = _old_positions[::3]
        y1 = _old_positions[1::3]
        z1 = _old_positions[2::3]

        x2 = new_positions[::3]
        y2 = new_positions[1::3]
        z2 = new_positions[2::3]


        old_verts = zip(x1, y1, z1)
        new_verts = zip(x2, y2, z2)

        # compare the old positions and new positions side by side
        # using enumerate() to keep track of the indices
        for idx, verts in enumerate(zip (old_verts, new_verts)):
            old, new = verts
            if old != new:
                # you'd replace this with the HUD printing code
                print idx, ":", new[0] - old[0],  new[1] - old[1], new[2] - old[2]

        # store the new positions for next time
        _old_positions = new_positions


#activate the script job and prime it
cmds.scriptJob(ac= ('pCubeShape1.outMesh', update_mesh_positions))
cmds.select('pCubeShape1')
update_mesh_positions()
# force an update so the first move is caught
```

This isn't really something Maya is good at doing via script: on big meshes this will be pretty slow since you're processing a lot of numbers.  For small examples it should work though.